# Do we need to merge node module folder in production environment for react-native app?

Tags: react-native, apk, node-modules, production-environment

Do we need to merge node module folder when code goes to production Do we need to merge node module folder in production for react-native app for react-native app.
If yes then why we need this folder and if no how can we ignore the folder.

Comment: No its not needed, node-module contains all the libraries which you have installed while development. If you want to setup your project in other system just use command `npm install` and it will create node-module folder with all those libraries which are mentioned in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

No need to manually merge something (e.g. node_modules) to the final app. 
You can, of course, use Android Studio or XCode to build the release version, but using below commands to package the apps will be much more handy:

```
//Build release version
react-native run-android --variant=release 
react-native run-ios --configuration Release
```

Reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html